# Create a countIfs function that ignores cells with text that has been struck through

Tags: vba, excel

Searching through the internet I was able to find some code that creates a countIf function that will not count a cell if there is strikethrough text in it.

```
Function MyCountif(rng As Range, s As String)
Application.Volatile
Dim i As Long, s1 As String, cell As Range
If Len(s) <> 1 Then
  MyCountif = CVErr(xlErrValue)
  Exit Function
End If
For Each cell In rng
  For i = 1 To Len(cell.Text)
    s1 = Mid(cell.Text, i, 1)
    If LCase(s1) = LCase(s) Then
      If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
         MyCountif = MyCountif + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
End Function
```

I was wondering if it was possible to make a similar function but instead in the form of a countIfs function that can also ignore the strikethrough text.

Edit: I don't have a ton of vba experience but I did give it a try myself. Since what I need it for will only need two ranges and two criteria I tried to put together something that ran the original function twice and if both criteria were met it would raise the count by one but I haven't quite gotten it to work.

```
Function MyCountif(rng As Range, s As String, rng2 As Range, p As String)
Application.Volatile
Dim i As Long, numbers(3) As Integer, numbers2(3) As Integer, s1 As String, cell As Range, j As Long, p1 As String, cell2 As Range, first As Long, second As Long
If Len(s) <> 1 Then
  MyCountif = CVErr(xlErrValue)
  Exit Function
End If
For Each cell In rng
  For i = 1 To Len(cell.Text)
    s1 = Mid(cell.Text, i, 1)
    If LCase(s1) = LCase(s) Then
      If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
         numbers(i) = 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
For Each cell2 In rng2
  For i = 1 To Len(cell2.Text)
    p1 = Mid(cell2.Text, i, 1)
    If LCase(p1) = LCase(p) Then
      If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
         numbers2(i) = 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
For i = 0 To 3
    If numbers(i) = 1 And numbers2(i) = 1 Then
        MyCountif = MyCountif + 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: I found an apple pie recipe but I wanted to make pumpkin pie, guess I am stuck asking the internet XD

Comment: All you'd do is add more `If` statements to whittle down the info.  @Findwindow - this is more like he's found an apple pie recipe, but wants to know how to add more apples.  ...just...add them?

Comment: Had a good discourse in the other thread Batman. Would've loved your thoughts =P Edit: re your comment above, but...but... it's easier asking the internet!

Comment: Actually, this is trickier than it seems because `countifs` takes variable number of arguments. Now I kinda feel bad about my comment XD Edit: well, not really, OP didn't show any effort.

Comment: @findwindow  But wouldn't you really just need to add some `If` or `IfElse` statements to whittle it down? `Countifs` is the same as `countif`, just more criteria has to be met.

Comment: The function as it's written takes the two arguments of `countif`. How would you restructure the function for `countifs`? This reminds me of the paramarray thread the other day XD Edit: am I thinking of `countifs` correctly XD Edit2: yea I am. There can be numerous ranges.

Comment: @Dan this "found" code does not do what you seem to think it does.  It take a single character input `s` and counts non-struck through _characters_ in each cell in `rng`

Comment: lol only @chrisneilsen read the code XD

Answer (score 1):

I guess here's the pumkin pie! I'm with @findwindow in that I'm not normally in the game of writing an OP's entire solution when there isn't much evidence in the original question of a serious attempt at it (perhaps there has been but the question is just a bit sparse on detail, so apologies if that is the case).

Anyhow, I've been sitting next to a two-year who just won't sleep for the last three hours ... and in between bouts of singing lullabies, threatening father Christmas won't come, stroking a nose, etc., etc. I had a crack at solving this problem.

I didn't have time to think about Excel's `CountIf` protocol for operators such as greater than, etc., so the last chunk of code just uses the `CountIf` function.

To the OP, if you're not that familiar with VBA then you should be aware that changing the format of cells to `Strikethrough` won't trigger a recalculation, so you'll either have to command that manually or capture the format change and force a recalculation (I'll let you research that bit for yourself).

You call the function by entering `Range` then value pairs. For example: `=MyCountIfs(A1:A10,">1",C1:C10,"B")`.

```
Public Function MyCountIfs(ParamArray rngCriterionPairs() As Variant) As Variant

    '============================================================================================
    'Purpose:   applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and aggregates counter for each
    '           successful match of criterion against cell value in the respective range.
    '
    'Usage:     user must enter one pair of range and criterion values and may enter further
    '           value pairs in the sequence [range, criterion, range, criterion ...]
    '
    'Notes:     1. Ranges do not need to be equal in size and do not need to be contiguous.
    '           2. Criteria use Excel's CountIf protocol so, for example, ">2" can be used.
    '           3. Although this function uses Application.Volatile, changes to cell formats
    '              won't trigger a recacalculation.
    '============================================================================================

    Application.Volatile

    Dim rangeCriteriaList As Collection 'collection of range/criterion pairs
    Dim rcp(1) As Variant               'range/criterion pair
    Dim filteredRange As Range          'range object with strikethrough cells removed
    Dim workingARange As Boolean        'toggle for testing range-criterion sequence
    Dim objTest As Object               'redundant object used for object testing
    Dim item As Variant                 'variant required to loop through collection
    Dim cell As Range                   'range object required to loop through cells in range
    Dim block As Range                  'range object required to loop through areas in range
    Dim count As Integer                'aggregates the number of successful hits
    Dim i As Integer                    'looping variable for paramarray index

    'Test the ParamArray paramters
    'Must be entered as Range then Variant pairs.
    'Excel's CountIfs requires ranges of equal size but we don't need to do that.
    'First check parameter has at least two values
    If IsEmpty(rngCriterionPairs) Then
            MyCountIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)
            Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsArray(rngCriterionPairs) Then
        MyCountIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'It's an array so loop through the array values
    'We'll work through each item and, if it's a Range add it to our rcp(0) variable
    'This caters for Ranges separated by commas.
    'Once the value isn't a range then it'll be assigned to rcp(1).
    'The subsequent value must therefore be a Range and the range test is toggled on/off
    'with the workingARange boolean.

    Set rangeCriteriaList = New Collection
    workingARange = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(rngCriterionPairs)
        If TypeName(rngCriterionPairs(i)) = "Range" Then
            Set filteredRange = NonStrikeThroughCells(rngCriterionPairs(i))
            If Not workingARange Then workingARange = True
            If Not filteredRange Is Nothing Then
                If IsEmpty(rcp(0)) Then 'it's a new range
                    Set rcp(0) = filteredRange
                Else 'it's a non-contiguous range so union with old range
                    Set rcp(0) = Union(rcp(0), filteredRange)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            'It's not a range so workingARange toggle must be set true
            If Not workingARange Then
                MyCountIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                Exit Function
            Else
                'Toggle the workingARange boolean to false
                workingARange = False
                'Ignore if the reference range wasn't set
                If Not IsEmpty(rcp(0)) Then
                    'Range then non-range rule is valid, so check the value isn't an object
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set objTest = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
                    Set objTest = rngCriterionPairs(i): On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not objTest Is Nothing Then
                        MyCountIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                    'It's not an object so we'll use it
                    rcp(1) = rngCriterionPairs(i)
                    'Add the range/critrion pair to collection
                    rangeCriteriaList.Add rcp
                    'Clear the rcp values
                    Erase rcp
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Test the last item wasn't a Range
    If workingARange Then
        MyCountIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Loop through the collection of ranges and run the count test
    'I've used Excel's CountIf function to avoid catering in the code
    'for the ">2" type of arguments.
    'Purists can have a crack at this within the commented-out block if they wish.
    count = 0
    For Each item In rangeCriteriaList
        For Each block In item(0).Areas
            count = count + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(block, item(1))
        Next
        'For Each cell In item(0).Cells
            'If cell.Value = item(1) Then count = count + 1
        'Next
    Next

    'Return the count
    MyCountIfs = count

End Function
Private Function NonStrikeThroughCells(rngVar As Variant) As Range
    'Removes strikethrough cells from range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim result As Range

    Set rng = rngVar
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If Not cell.Font.Strikethrough Then
            If result Is Nothing Then
                Set result = cell
            Else
                Set result = Union(result, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set NonStrikeThroughCells = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your function to return an array of TRUE/FALSE, and use that in a simple array SUM function to do the other conditions rather than over-complicate your VBA

```
Public Function HasStrikeThrough(rng As Range) As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim idx As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ary As Variant

    Application.Volatile

    ReDim ary(1 To rng.Cells.Count)

    For Each cell In rng
        idx = idx + 1
        ary(idx) = False
        For i = 1 To Len(cell.Text)
            If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then ary(idx) = True
        Next
    Next

    HasStrikeThrough = Application.Transpose(ary)
End Function
```

and your worksheet formula would be like this

```
=SUM((B1:B10="a")*(C1:C10="y")*(HasStrikeThrough(D1:D10)))
```

Comment: i also got that idea... however... arrays like this will take a lot of time to calculate if there lots of cells/conditions... right now i'm struck to make it useable in a countif or other functions which use ranges and disallow arrays :/

Comment: And you think the VBA won't ... ?

Comment: Doing it line by line and not all at once is faster... while I would not look at each single character. Also most functions use the `UsedRange` property internally. This way I would just create an array with the size like A:A but calculate only till line 100 (if there ends the used range). Just test it with countifs for ranges of whole columns and then do the same with your array formula. The difference can be significantly :)